# Linear Local Embedding Residual Variance Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, machine-learning, scientific-computing

I am trying to reproduce linear local embedding in matlab. Now I am able to get the Y vectors for this. However, what I am unclear about is getting the residual variance. I was wondering if perhaps someone has run into this issue and has an algorithm for how they went about programming this in matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [dimensionality reduction toolbox](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/drtoolbox/) implements LLE (among many other nonlinear dimensionality reduction techniques). Very easy to use and a great toolbox, so if you don't *really* need to implement it yourself you could use it, or otherwise look into their code for inspiration?